# Jdk для 32-bit системы windows

Tags: android, java

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

У меня 32 разрядная система, не могу найти под неё jdk, получается, мне нужно сносить винду?
Установил jdk for Windows x86, при запуске android studio выдаёт "No jvm instalations found, install a 32 -bit jdk".

Правильно ли я понимаю, что установил не ту jdk?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно менять винду? (Или есть выход?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 и есть 32 разрядная. Вы, скорей всего, в переменные окружения в PATH не прописали путь к вашему jvk.

Comment: нет...сейчас попробую

Comment: спасибо, помогло